# How to set "Last successful build" value for a job through Jenkins API?

Tags: api, jenkins, model, jobs

Regarding the data displayed in the "Permalinks" section of the Job Status page in Jenkins, I know there are methods to get the values. For example ...

```
jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("&lt;job&gt;").getLastSuccessfulBuild()
```

However, I can't find any method to change the "Last successful build" value on the screen.
Editing the symbolic link `$HOME/.jenkins/jobs/&lt;job&gt;/builds/lastSuccessfulBuild`, then running `jenkins.instance.doReload()` does not cause the gui screen display to be updated.

Is there a way to do this through the API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the call for get the value using the API:

http://$host/job/$jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json

You can try to modificate the json and to do a POST with the new Json after.